# MYSQL Syntax Error, unexpected while_sym, expecting END_OF_INPUT or ';'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an archiving event, and what I came up with look like this:

```
SET @Date = NULL;
SET @SEDOL = NULL;
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS Archive_Event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
SELECT @Date = Date,@SEDOL = SEDOL
from daily.analytics
where   Date =  (SELECT MIN(Date)
                 from daily.analytics 
                 WHERE Date < date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY))
order by SEDOL desc limit 1

WHILE @date is not null
begin
    begin transaction
    -- Adds old line to archive
    insert into daily.Archive_analytics
        select * from daily.analytics where Date = @Date AND SEDOL = @SEDOL
    -- Deletes old line from main table
    delete from daily.analytics where Date = @Date AND SEDOL = @SEDOL
    commit transaction
    -- Find the next greater minimum value
    SELECT @Date = Date,@SEDOL = SEDOL
    from daily.analytics
    where   Date =  (SELECT MIN(Date)
                     from daily.analytics 
                     WHERE Date < date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY))
     order by SEDOL desc
     limit 1
END WHILE
END
```

Searching the web this seems to be more or less correct, however my WHILE statement is getting a "Syntax Error, unexpected while_sym,  expecting END_OF_INPUT or ';'" and I'm not quite sure why.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Where is the `end` for the `begin` after the `while` ?

Comment: I guess you should have an **end** inside WHILE loop for **begin**

Comment: Do you guys mean the "begin transaction"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was due to delimiters and having multiple blocks in the code. The version without syntax errors looks like this:

```
SET @Date = NULL;
SET @SEDOL = NULL;

delimiter |
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS daily.Archive_Event_HOUR
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
    begin
    SELECT @Date = Date,@SEDOL = SEDOL
    from daily.analytics
    where   Date =  (SELECT MIN(Date)
                     from daily.analytics 
                     WHERE Date < date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY))
    order by SEDOL desc limit 1;

    WHILE @Date is not null DO
        start transaction;
        -- Adds old line to archive
        insert into daily.Archive_analytics
            select * from daily.analytics where Date = @Date AND SEDOL = @SEDOL;
        -- Deletes old line from main table
        delete from daily.analytics where Date = @Date AND SEDOL = @SEDOL;
        commit;
        -- Find the next greater minimum value
        SELECT @Date = Date,@SEDOL = SEDOL
        from daily.analytics
        where   Date =  (SELECT MIN(Date)
                         from daily.analytics 
                         WHERE Date < date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY))
         order by SEDOL desc
         limit 1;
    END WHILE;
END|
delimiter ;
```